# Subquery Django by multiple columns

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to Subquery in Django by multiple columns?

I want to get the latest instance of each type.

```
sq = OrderedModel.objects.annotate(
    latest=Window(
      expression=Max("order"),
      partition_by=["type"]
    )
)
```

Something like this:

`OrderedModel.objects.filter(type=sq.type, sq.latest)`

Comment: `latest` by which parameter? Did you try `.all().last()`? Which returns last element in the queryset.

Comment: Thats not what i tried to query. 
In words: Get the highest "order" column per "type".

I'm using a raw query now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Subquery`. you can use `values` to do the `group_by` from **SQL**.

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

OrderedModel.objects.values("type").annotate(highest_order=Max("order")).values("type", "order")
```

**example of ouput**

*<QuerySet [{'type': "Cereals", "highest_order": 5000}]>*